# why css classes not applied under link function

Tags: angularjs-directive

i have a template includes elements like following

```
 <span class="arrow"></span>
```

style look like this :

```
 .arrow{ width : 12px; }
```

inside directive

```
 link : function($scope, element, attribute)
 {
      //get element width 
 }
```

in result i see width fn returns 0, why css classes not get applied? i added more elements into template, other elements css classes get not applied as well

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just use the `width()`:

```
link: function($scope, element, attribute)
{
    console.log( element.width() );
}
```

Comment: it produces 0 , doesn't work, i guess it should first added to dom so that css classes get applied

Comment: Is your directive for the `span`?

Comment: Also, not an ideal solution, but you could use `$timeout(function(){ element.width(); }, 0)`. The `0` here means run once the DOM has finished rendering.